# During Installation Cordova (PhoneGap) I am getting warning like "npm WARN engine Cordova-js@3. 8.0: wanted:..."

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to develop PhoneGap application, So I am trying to install cordova on the **window** using the procedure mention in  [this link](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0//guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface).

**1.** Node.js
**2.** git client
**3.** npm install npm -g
 I use above step-3,([Please see](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3624)) to get rid from this warning, did not succeed
**4** npm install -g cordova

But I am getting the follwing warning.

```
C:\>npm install -g cordova
npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.8.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"
0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":
"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {
"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
C:\Users\Neelabh\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> C:\Users\Neelabh\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
cordova@4.3.0 C:\Users\Neelabh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.5)
└── cordova-lib@4.3.0 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.
2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11, unorm@1.3.3, semver@2.0.11, shelljs@0.3.0
, dep-graph@1.1.0, rc@0.5.2, elementtree@0.1.5, xcode@0.6.7, d8@0.4.4, glob@4.0.
6, npmconf@0.1.16, through2@0.6.3, init-package-json@1.3.0, request@2.47.0, tar@
1.0.2, plist@1.1.0, cordova-js@3.8.0, npm@1.3.4)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

don't worry about the warning,

nodejs 0.12 were just release last mounth, Cordova team havn't yet update dependencies.

Another thing the most up to date Cordova build is 4.1.2, try :

```
npm install -g cordova@4
```

to force npm installing the newer version. Cordova 4 works with both 0.10 and 0.12 nodejs version but will warn you as the 3.8 version. Things should return at normal soon after teams updates all the dependencies.

If you really want to care about that warning you could downgrade your nodejs installation to 0.10 and everything will return as usual.

Hope that help.

Comment: I already install cordoav, So If I run this It will create any problem?

Comment: none, cordova is a really stable software. And the change between 3.8 and 4 isn't on basics stuff so even with an 3.8 cordova project you can use cordova 4 ;). enjoy it

Comment: Sorry, i forgot. Have a nice day and enjoy cordova

Answer (score 0):

Installing below 0.12 versions of Node.js solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just went to NODEjs site and it updated after download.